# PHP Factory Method Pattern Implementation

Tags: php, factory-method

This is an attempt at the Factory Method Pattern
It emulates the logical model [image: Client--Factory--Product]

and also the physical model

[image]

Resources:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx

http://www.oodesign.com/factory-pattern.html

Is this a correct implementation of the Factory Method Pattern? I think I have followed all the required features of it. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
/** contract for all flyable vehicles **/
interface iFlyable {
    public function fly();
}

/* concrete implementations of iFlyable interface */
class JumboJet implements iFlyable {
    public function fly() {
        return "Flying 747!";
    }
}

class FighterJet implements iFlyable {
    public function fly() {
        return "Flying an F22!";
    }
}

class PrivateJet implements iFlyable {
    public function fly() {
        return "Flying a Lear Jet!";
    }
}

/** contract for conrete Factory **/
/**
* "Define an interface for creating an object, but let the classes that implement the interface
* decide which class to instantiate. The Factory method lets a class defer instantiation to
* subclasses."
**/
interface iFlyableFactory {
    public static function create( $flyableVehicle );
}

/** concrete factory **/
class JetFactory implements iFlyableFactory {
    /* list of available products that this specific factory makes */
    private  static $products = array( 'JumboJet', 'FighterJet', 'PrivateJet' );

    public  static function create( $flyableVehicle ) {
        if( in_array( $flyableVehicle, JetFactory::$products ) ) {
            return new $flyableVehicle;
        } else {
            throw new Exception( 'Jet not found' );
        }
    }
}

$militaryJet = JetFactory::create( 'FighterJet' );
$privateJet = JetFactory::create( 'PrivateJet' );
$commercialJet = JetFactory::create( 'JumboJet' );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$militaryJet = JetFactory::create( 'FighterJet' );
$privateJet = JetFactory::create( 'PrivateJet' );
$commercialJet = JetFactory::create( 'JumboJet' );
```

This is a Factory pattern.  I'm not sure that I'd call it the Factory method pattern.  Look at the Wikipedia example for C# -- this looks like the before version.  If you were doing the same thing as the after version here, you'd have

```
$militaryJet = FighterJetFactory::create();
$privateJet = PrivateJetFactory::create();
$commercialJet = JumboJetFactory::create();
```

Where `FighterJetFactory`, `PrivateJetFactory`, and `JumboJetFactory` would all extend or implement `JetFactory`.

The question here is why not just say

```
$militaryJet = new FighterJet();
$privateJet = new PrivateJet();
$commercialJet = new JumboJet();
```

Given this example, you don't need any variation of the Factory pattern.  You could just create the objects directly.  As a general rule, you shouldn't look to use design patterns.  You should meet problems that can be solved by the design pattern.  You don't have a problem that needs a design pattern to solve.

Example of a problem that needs a Factory pattern solution:  given a passenger count and a cargo weight, return an object representing a plane that is capable of carrying those passengers with that cargo.

Example of a problem that needs a factory method solution:  define an interface for a plane and another that will allow you to create a plane object.  Give the interfaces to two partners.  Have one write a `BoeingFactory` that implements your factory interface and the other an `AirbusFactory`.  Both should return plane objects that implement your plane interface.

Comment: Well, like they say, "There are several implementations of it."  With the iFylable interface you can add other concrete products like: Rocket, Helicopter. No worries. It was just an exercise for a textbook.